# Typescript/d3, can't dynamically provide symbol types

Tags: typescript, d3.js

I'm trying to extend a network visualisation tool, enabling the user to set custom symbols for the nodes in the network. When trying to dynamically set this shape, I get the error:

```
Error: <path> attribute d: Expected moveto path command ('M' or 'm'), "function n(n,r){…".
```

Which looks to me like instead of giving it actual path data returned by a function, I'm passing the function itself.

I've looked at the javascript code to similar problems here [Setting d3 symbol conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52571485/setting-d3-symbol-conditionally) and here [Passing a function to .attr('d')?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49520535/passing-a-function-to-attrd) . I also tried a similar use case in typescript here https://github.com/abchakra/d3_work/blob/7b602690615790d38b00832750ead637c66e205d/gantt_ts/app/ts/lib/ganttChart.ts but it seems to be using a different version of typescript? (in the line `.attr("d", d => d3.symbol().size(2400).type(d.symbol)());` no type is provided for `d`?)

I've simplifed what I'm trying to do slightly to make the problem more obvious. 
Intuitively the code below should assign the type of the symbol to 'circle', and indeed if I just paste the string in there (`.attr('d', d3.svg.symbol().type('circle'))`) it works fine. If I try to pass through the `d` parameter in any way however, the function itself seems to be passed through as the path and I get the error above.

```
    var shape = function(d: any){
        return 'circle';
    }

    visualNodes = nodeLayer.selectAll('nodes')
        .data(nodes)
        .enter()
        .append('path')
        .attr('d', (d: any) => d3.svg.symbol().type(shape(d)))
        .attr('class', 'nodes')
        .style('fill', (n: dynamicgraph.Node) => getNodeColor(n))
         ...
        })
```

I'd like to be able to use the d parameter in the shape var to assign the shape dynamically, I could probably hack my way around the problem in some way - but I'd like to at least understand why d3 is using the function itself as the path and why passing `d` through changes that.

Answer (score 1):

`.attr('d', (d: any) => d3.svg.symbol().type(shape(d))())` gives a TS2349 error - so I had dismissed it before - but seems to work properly if that error is suppressed.